# SharedPrefs simple saving not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I get the following in W/ Log when saving preferences

```
08-22 16:31:14.749  16851-17822/com.xxx.xxx W/System.err﹕ remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.xxx.xxx/shared_prefs/xxxPrefs.xml.bak
```

the code in question

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
            prefsEditor.putInt("user_id", Integer.parseInt(json.getJSONObject(0).getString("user_id")));
            prefsEditor.commit();
```

the user_id is indeed a string like "1" and gets parsed properly, its not that.

Comment: Just to be sure, replace the 0 (Zero) when creating the Sharedreferences Object with MODE_PRIVATE

Comment: I got the same thing, and MODE_PRIVATE is 0, just checked.

Comment: You should read back the preference later to see whether or not it was saved. This message in the log does not by itself mean there is a problem.

Comment: Whether these two things will make a difference, I don't know but my working code for SharedPreferences has "Context.MODE_PRIVATE" at the end instead of "0" and I import android.content.Context  .. and also I usually keep my prefs file name as a string in strings.xml and refer to it like so -getString(R.string.preference_file_key)

Comment: Also, try "prefsEditor.apply()" instead of "prefsEditor.commit()"